# linux shell - adding full stop (period) to end of lines which do not end with full stop, in a corpus

Tags: shell, text, sed, awk, end-of-line

I have a big corpus which is segmented at the sentence level. That means each line contains one sentence. Some of these lines end with full stop (period) some don't. 
I am looking for an efficient way to add full stops to the end of the lines which don't end with one. For instance a shell script that benefits from sed or awk to do this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sed is probably the simplest approach for this:

```
$ cat file
sentence one
sentence two.
sentence three

$ sed 's/[^.]$/&./' file
sentence one.
sentence two.
sentence three.
```

On lines that don't end with a period `[^.]$` replace the last character with the matched last character followed by a period `&.`. You should watch out for lines with trailing spaces that might contain the period as the last viable character.

**Edit**:

With `awk` I would do:

```
$ awk '/[^.]$/{$(NF+1)="."}1' FS= OFS= file
sentence one.
sentence two.
sentence three.
```

Comment: Can I challenge you to do it with awk? :D

Comment: @fedorqui not really a challenge haha :P

Comment: Alternatively a sed-ish awk: `awk '{sub(/[^.]$/, "&.", $0); print}' file`

Comment: You are a master, I would +1 again : D

Comment: @progo cutting the fat `awk '{sub(/[^.]$/,"&.")}1' file`